# firebase authentication for bare react native project - users not updated to database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have made a bare react native project (not expo). And now I want to add firebase authentication using email and password. I used useState and following code for that. But when I enter the data from the UI and click the button nothing get updated to the firebase.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Alert, View, Image, TouchableOpacity,Text,TextInput, ScrollView,PasswordInputText } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

function App() {
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password,setPassword] = useState('')

    auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User account created & signed in!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
      console.log('That email address is already in use!');
    }

    if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
      console.log('That email address is invalid!');
    }

    console.error(error);
  });
  // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  // Handle user state changes
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;


  if (!user) {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style= {styles.container0}>
            <Image style={styles.image2} source={require('../assets/imges/white.png')}/>
          </View>

          <Image style={styles.image1} source={require('../assets/imges/user.png')}/>
          <TextInput style={styles.input1} 
            placeholder="User name"
          />
          <TextInput style={styles.input2} 
            placeholder="Partner name"
          />

          <TextInput style={styles.input2} 
            placeholder="Wedding date"
          />

          <TextInput style={styles.input2} 
            placeholder="Email address"
            value={email}
            onChangeText={text=>setEmail(text)}
            
          />
          <TextInput style={styles.input2} 
            placeholder="Password"
            value={password}
            onChangeText={text=>setPassword(text)}
            secureTextEntry
          />
          

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button1}
              onPress={()=>{registration}}>
              
              <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Sing Up</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity> 
          <Text style={styles.text1}>Sign up with</Text>

          <View style ={styles.container1}>
            <Image style={styles.image3} source={require('../assets/imges/facebook.png')}/>
            <Image style={styles.image4} source={require('../assets/imges/google.png')}/>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

can someone please point out the issue ?

Comment: You are calling auth() in the render loop, this will happen every single time the component renders. You are also calling auth() in a mount effect. Did you mean to make the first auth() a function and not a function call?

Comment: @windowsill I took it as a function call, but I am not sure about the second one because I thought it is needed for listening to the authentication state.

Comment: Writing `auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)` in the function body of this component will call the function every time the component renders. Surely that can't be what you mean to do.